# Add custom text when product is on backorder using manage stock

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, status

I'm trying to display a custom text when products have the status of BACKORDER. I don't want to use woocommerce_get_availabilty_text as it causes conflict with a plugin that is displaying "AVAILABLE ON BACKORDER" text, I want an addition to the plugin text with custom text that would display on all products having the status of "backorder"
My attempted code:

```
   add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_action_after_single_product_title', 25 );
    function custom_action_after_single_product_title() { 
    global $product; 


     if (! $product->managing_stock() && $product->is_on_backorder() ){
        $text = __('      ,      1  (         )', 'woocommerce');
        $color = 'color:#bf0606;';
        $font  = 'itlaic';
    }
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you considered simply adding some text into the template hook? For example adding it before or after the summary or title or price etc. 
If so you could just use that instead so it doesn't conflict with any other plugins.

Comment: Yes, But I just want to display the text only when product is on backorder.So there will be no text if product is in stock, or out of stock.

Comment: You can use the same condition as above, just change the hook name to the name of the position you want the text to show. I'll post an answer as an example and you can develop from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED. I managed to get this to work for a product that was out of stock but on back order.

Check out this link for the other hooks you can use on the product page.
https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/

```
function custom_action_after_single_product_title() {

    //Declare global product variable
    global $product; 

    //Check to see if product is on back order
    if ( $product->is_on_backorder() == true ){

        //Spit out some text
        echo '<p>Your text here</p>';

    }

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'custom_action_after_single_product_title', 20 );
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your effort but unfortunately, the code didn't work.

Comment: Ok, Ill test it on a fresh install and update